# Cloudflare workers security and visibility

Tags: cloudflare-workers

My question is simple. I want to run some admin sdks and secure keys in cloudflare workers environment so can anyone look in to my code(even cloudflare) or inject something in it my top priority is security.
I am using dart and free plan of cloudflare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Cloudflare employees will have the ability to look at your code if needed for debugging problems with the Cloudflare Workers platform. Nobody outside Cloudflare will be able to see your code, and no one can modify your code without your permission.

For secret keys specifically, you should not embed the keys in your code. You can upload the secrets separately using the `wrangler secret` command, and then refer to them in your code. If you do this, no one will be able to look at your secrets, including Cloudflare employees.

Here's the blog post introducing Workers secrets: https://blog.cloudflare.com/workers-secrets-environment/